# Generate several lists from one list

Tags: list, workflow, designer-workflow, flow, power-automate

I'm working on a risk analysis and mitigation scheme. I want to keep track of different risks within a list. As there are different classes of risks (time delay, direct money loss, nonperformance) I have added a column (multiple select) to reflect that type. I don't want to have the individual columns dealing with the specialities of the different risk types in every line. I thought about defining content types, but an object can only be of one content type, while a certain risk in a project can inflict e.g. time delay as well as money loss.
My idea is now to have three more lists auto generated from the main list, containing all the elements belonging to a certain risk class. I tried to use lookup columns, but they don't do anything automatically. I think the biggest difficulty stems from the fact, that I want the elements of a list to be copies of the elements in the master list but also be able to hold individual data inside that smaller list.

My fallback solution is to put everything in my master list and use filtered views. But I consider that messy.

Any clues?

Comment: Best way is to copy the risk from master list to individual list using designer workflow or Microsoft flow/Power Automate based on the risk class on new risk creation in master list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your requirements, Best way is to copy the risk from master list to individual list by using **SharePoint designer workflow** or **Microsoft flow/Power Automate** (If you are using SharePoint Online) based on the risk class on new risk creation in master list.

**SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013**:

You can use **Create List Item** action to create a list item in new list based on the risk class.

**Documentation**: [Workflow actions in SharePoint Designer 2013 - List actions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/workflow-actions-quick-reference-sharepoint-workflow-platform#list-actions).

**Microsoft flow/Power Automate**:

You can achieve similar using Microsoft flow/Power Automate if you are using SharePoint Online.

**Reference**:

1. [Microsoft flow copy list items to another list](https://www.sharepointsky.com/microsoft-flow-copy-list-items-to-another-list/).
2. [Copy SharePoint list items between two lists using MS Flow](https://sureshunakka87.wordpress.com/2018/07/19/copy-sharepoint-list-items-between-two-lists-using-ms-flow/).

**SharePoint Designer Workflow 2010** (Not recommended, Personally):

You can achieve similar using **Copy List Item** in SharePoint Designer Workflow 2010.

**Documentation**: [Workflow actions in SharePoint Designer 2010: A quick reference guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-5a7ad276-0ed7-49b0-b652-e56a77dd96c6).

Comment: I'm currently implementing the recommendations step by step. Looks good, so far!

Comment: Great, try it and let me know if it works for you or if you come across any issue.

Comment: I think, these tutorials should work, but I'm stuck at some point. I think I'll post a new question.